# Minimum number of edges required to limit the size of the independent set

Tags: clique, independent-sets

Consider the following problem:

> For $k \le n$, what is the smallest number of edges in the graph with $n$ vertices so that the maximum independent set has size at most $k$?

I.e., given an empty graph on $n$ vertices, I want to add the smallest number of edges so that the maximum independent set has size $k$.
Let's denote it as $A(n,k)$.
For example, $A(8,3)=7$, with edges $1-2-3-1$, $4-5-6-4$ and $7-8$ (two triangles and an edge).

I know that $A(n,k) \le T(n-1, k)$ where $T$ is https://oeis.org/A134546.
In particular, I know that $A(n,n) = 0$ and $A(n + 1,k) \le A(n, k) + \lfloor n / k \rfloor$.

The particular construction is to maintain $k$ cliques so that the independent set can pick only vertex per clique.
For example, for $A(8,3)$, the solution $1-2-3-1$, $4-5-6-4$ and $7-8$ consists of three cliques $(1,2,3)$, $(4,5,6)$, and $(7,8)$.
When we add another vertex, we have $A(9,3) \le A(8,3) + 2$, since we can add edges $8-9$ and $7-9$ to have cliques $(1,2,3)$, $(4,5,6)$, and $(7,8,9)$.

**Q**: How to prove that we have equality, i.e. $A(n + 1,k) = A(n, k) + \lfloor n / k \rfloor$? My experiments show that it indeed holds, and, intuitively, it should hold.

I suspect there is some relation to [Clique Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover), but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You might find Turan's theorem helpful: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem

Comment: @jschnei, Thanks, this does provide a very good bound, but, unfortunately, it doesn't show equality. E.g., assuming that what I want to prove is in fact correct, starting from $n \ge 12$, the Turan's theorem starts underestimating the number of edges.

Comment: I am confused, if I understand your question correctly Turan's theorem should provide a tight bound. Note that an independent set is just a clique in the complement graph, so your question is equivalent to asking "what is the largest number of edges a graph with n vertices can have so that the maximum clique has size at most k"? This is exactly answered by Turan's theorem.

Comment: For $n=12$ and $k=8$, the answer is $4$, while Turan predicts $\ge 3$. This is if I use the last expression from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem#Statement (see also https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-662-57265-8_41.pdf), which gives ${12 \choose 2} - (1-\frac{1}{8}) \cdot \frac{12^2}{2} = 3$. Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: If you read carefully, you'll see that the formula you are using is only an asymptotic bound. The actual "tight" value is given by some $(k-1)$-partite graph. You can phrase this as finding k-1 positive integers x_1, x_2, ..., x_{k-1} that sum to n and that maximize the sum_{i < j} x_ix_j. It is not too hard to show that to do this you want to set each x_i to either floor(n/(k-1)) or ceil(n/(k-1)).

Comment: Thanks, I see now. (It's clear that if optimal graphs are always complete $k$-partite graphs, than you are done. What wasn't clear is why complete $k$-partite graphs are optimal.)